# Regression / Predictive Methods for Arbitrary Input and Output with Intervals

Tags: regression, error-propagation, interval-arithmetic

Does anybody know any regression/prediction/supervised learning method if I have arbitrary independent and dependent variables with Intervals?

For example, I have an observation with epistemic uncertainty that modeled as interval such as:

| x_1 | x_2 | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1,3] | [3,4] | [-1,0] |
| [-2,0] | [1,4] | [4,5.5] |
| [2,3] | [6,8] | [5,8] |
| ... | ... | ... |

How can I model this kind of data with regression technique?

I found some solutions mentioned *interval censored data*. But I guess, that's not the case. I also found some others, but they seem to only allow the uncertainty propagation from the independent variable to the dependent variables. Meanwhile, in my case, I think I need to include the interval dependent variable into the fitting/training process.

Does anybody knows any reference for this problem?